# PHP Bizarre behaviour with switch() and logical or (XOR) in a case declaration

Tags: php, php-5.3, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

**NOTE: I am aware that this is not acceptable code, I am seeking to understand what the interpreter is doing, not advice on how else to achieve the same result!**

I've since read up enough to realize that I can't and shouldn't be attempting to use |,|| or XOR in defining a switch case—so please don't comment to the effect of "don't do that", I'm just trying to understand what the interpreter is *doing* with such statements and to understand the strangeness of the behavior. I'm using PHP 5.3.1.

This is what I was actually intending to do and am now using, please don't recommend code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($this->header); $i++) {
            switch($i) {
                case 0:
                    $this->header[ $i ] = $this->header[ $i ] ? $this->header[ $i ] : -5;   //angle from goal
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -5;         //miss penalty
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -10;         //miss penalty
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $this->header[ $i ] = $this->header[ $i ] ? $this->header[ $i ] : -10;  //error penalty
                    break;
            }
        }
```

But got curious if I could do:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($this->header); $i++) {
            switch($i) {
                case 0 || 1:
                    $this->header[ $i ] = $this->header[ $i ] ? $this->header[ $i ] : 15;   //angle from goal
                    break;
                case 2 || 3:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -5;         //miss penalty
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and, perversely, this does run, but *very* slowly (like, seconds), and though of course it evaluates `(0||1)` not at all the way I'd intended (and indeed today was a lesson on the difference between bitwise and logical operators).

But more curious to me was the fact that I could do this, if very slowly and not with the results I'd wanted:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($this->header); $i++) {
            switch($i) {
                case 0 XOR 1:
                    $this->header[ $i ] = $this->header[ $i ] ? $this->header[ $i ] : 15;   //angle from goal
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -5;         //miss penalty
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -5;         //miss penalty
                    break;
            }
        }
```

But I could *not* do this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($this->header); $i++) {
            switch($i) {
                case 0 XOR 1:
                    $this->header[ $i ] = $this->header[ $i ] ? $this->header[ $i ] : 15;   //angle from goal
                    break;
                case 2 XOR 3:
                    $this->header[$i] = $this->header[$i] ? $this->header[$i] : -5;         //miss penalty
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This was the only one of these terrible, terrible ideas that PHP wouldn't even evaluate.

My question is: why does evaluating these statements take so, so much longer, and why does the last example not run? I considered that PHP was interpreting 0 XOR 1 and comparing `true` and `false`, but I couldn't substitute those in and have it still evaluate. Anyone know what's happening here? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Comments requested a `var_dump($this->header)` (in case it isn't obvious, I truncated my initial switch statement from 7 cases to 4 just to avoid spamming lines of identical code, but, given that the `var_dump()` was requested, I chose to post the whole thing in case it revealed something I couldn't forsee!). Also, yes, it turns out I'd been using an associative array due to forgetting to have called `array_values()` before setting `$this->header`, in the second answer below, having made this error turns out to explain the duration of the `switch` statement, whilst the first answer and second answer together are great walkthroughs of the logic.

```
array(12) {
  ["theZone"]=>
  NULL
  ["leftMiss"]=>
  NULL
  ["rightMiss"]=>
  NULL
  ["leftError"]=>
  NULL
  ["rightError"]=>
  NULL
  ["leftHit"]=>
  NULL
  ["rightHit"]=>
  NULL
  ["accuracy"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["rt"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["disease"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["bars"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["endMessage"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: You can replicate the behaviour of `case 0 || 1:` by using `case 0:` followed by `case 1:` without a `break;` instruction in between them.

Comment: That's handy,I hadn't thought of that, thanks! But really, I wasn't trying to do anything but type less, haha. Truly this was just an experiment to see what PHP would let me do, and I just don't understand what, fundamentally, is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` values have to be SINGLE values. You can't do `2 || 3`, because that'll evaluate as

```
case (2 or 3) -> case TRUE
```

Similarly, if you were using `&&` (`and`), you'd get

```
case (0 and 1) -> case FALSE
```

You can use 'fallthrough' behavior for the `OR` logic:

```
case 2:
case 3:
   ...code here ...
   break;
```

XOR, you can't do. not with a simple case statement.

comment followup:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
   switch($i) {
       case 0 xor 1:  echo "0 xor 1: $i\n"; break;
       case 2 xor 3:  echo "2 xor 3: $i\n"; break;
   }
}
```

will output

```
2x3: 0
0x1: 1
0x1: 2
0x1: 3
0x1: 4
```

and

```
php > var_dump(2 xor 3);
bool(false)
php > var_dump(0 xor 1);
bool(true)
```

Remember that switch cases evaluate the same `==`. They're lazy comparisons, not checking types. So your `2 xor 3` is evaluated the same as if the case has been `case false`, which makes the $i=0 condition match.

Comment: Except you can! I agree that you shouldn't; I never thought any of these would run, but all of them DO evaluate except the final one. What is bizarre is that it takes a very long time to do so, and of course, semantically, they don't mean anything like "if the case is one or two do x". I just want to understand WHY the interpreter would do the first three at all, and why it took so long!

Comment: Ahhhh. Beauty, this explains to me what was happening logically, as it were, truly thank you for taking the time to do this. 

If I tell you that `$this->header` was (and this is embarrassing, haha) actually an associative array of length 12, can you see any reason why it would take literally seconds to evaluate? Again, just curiosity, I moved on from this in the actual project hours ago, I just like to learn!

Answer (score 2):

Haha, it's quite funny, what you did there.

It's not the switch which gets you into performance troubles. It probably is your for-loop in combination with your switch.

I try to explain it with the second example given.

However, I just have to guess, and so I have to assume that your $this->header array looks like the following (this would be the only reason for your performance leak):

```
$this->header = array(
  999 => 10,   // the value is irrelevant, only the key (2) matters
  998 => 15
);
```

Now lets play interpreter debugger.

```
set $i to 0
is $i<count($this->header)? yes, because header size is 2
is ($i == (0 || 1))? no, because (0 == (0 || 1)) equals (0 == true) equals (false == true) can never be true
is ($i == (2 || 3))? no, because (0 == (2 || 3)) equals (0 == true) equals (false == true) will never comply
next loop, increment $i (set $i to 1)
is ($i<count($this->header)? yes, because header size is 2
is ($i == (0 || 1))? yes, because (1 == (0 || 1)) equals (1 == true) equals (true == true)
go into case statement
set $this->header[1] to -5  (remember the index 1 does not exist so far in your array)
next loop, increment $i (set $i to 2)
is $i<count($this->header)? yes, because header size is 3 (remember? you just added a new index which incremented your header size)
is ($i == (0 || 1))? yes, because (2 == (0 || 1)) equals (2 == true equals (true == true)
go into case statement
set $this->header[2] to -5 (again index 2 did not exist so far)
next loop, increment $i (set $i to 3)
is $i<count($this->header)? yes, because header size is 4 (again, you just added a new index)
```

Now this will continue until the header size equals $i. In the example above this would happen after 998 iterations, because this would be the first time when there won't be a new index creation (the existing one - 998 - would simply be used), resulting in count($this->header) not changing.

In your first example, this will not happen. The header size will stop to change after the fourth iteration, because the case statement tries to compare integer values instead of booleans. As soon as it reaches index 5 it tries to compare to the values 1, 2, 3 and 4 and will not match a single one, resulting in no new index creation.

To fix the the performance issue, you should make sure that every key in your array exists and also change your for-loop as follows:

```
$size = count($this->header);
for($i=0; $i<$size); $i++) {...}
```

Of course this won't fix your logical problems. But since you asked for what is going on, this should be a good explanation, I guess.

var_dump()-ing your $this->header array before and after your loop should prove me right :)

===

Sorry for deleting and undeleting this answer. Just wanted to make sure it really behaves as explained. If you could provide me with a var_dump of your header array, it would be great.

Comment: So cool, thank you for going into details like this! However—and the irony here is that I might have missed this mistake for a while if I hadn't gone back to recreate this to test your theory—`$this->header` was actually an associative array (of length 12 no less!). I've been running the app in demo mode, so I was expecting the default values (-5/-10); turns out, all of those ternary operators were returning false because there *are* no integer indices. But I'm guessing this doesn't change your logic too much? Still, tons and tons of thanks, I learn so much by walking through the logic like so

Comment: Well, if there are only non-numeric indices, then your code should never finish properly. For example with `$this->header = array('foo' => 'bar', 'a' => 'b');` it would run into an infinite loop and simply quit at some point (out of memory or something similar). In some cases php seems to recognize these kind of infinite loops, resulting in an abrupt termination without an error. However, since you said you received some values, this doesn't fit your description. As I wrote before: a var_dump of your $this->header would help alot.

Comment: Posted the `var_dump()`; but I think this nailed it. I re-ran that code from before and I was mistaken on one detail—it wasn't, in fact, outputting the values from the loop above, but from print_r() calls I'd left in from debugging earlier in the program. I had considered a memory issue, but I'm accustomed to getting an error message from an infinite loop vis-a-vis `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated ########) (tried to allocate #### bytes)`, I had no idea PHP could produce an "abrupt termination without an error"; thanks agin so much, books just don't mention such nuances.

Comment: PS: I sometimes wish StackExchange would let more than one answer be labelled "correct", especially in circumstances like this where the answer is more academic and less methodological. I took a look through some of your other answers and upvoted a couple that struck me as especially elegant/useful, if for no other reason than to keep the rep-rewards even. Cheers again man, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you with that. And thanks for the upvotes. And by the way: instead of debugging your code with var_dump and print_r, you could use an IDE with debugger. For example PDT (based on eclipse) with xdebug or ZendStudio (also based on eclipse) with the ZendDebugger. In the second one, the debugger is allready integrated, but PDT is free.